# Viewing Source Code Explorer in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio

Can you please tell me how to view Source Code Explorer in VS Community Edition 2017 and what it is used for?

Answer (score 0):

well, Source Code Explorer is for managing changes made in your project when using TFVC ( Team Foundation Version Control which is a centralized version control system in VS )

TO access it : View, Other Windows, Source Control Explorer. ( it is known to have issues on 2017 ) 
check this for reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/use-source-control-explorer-manage-files-under-version-control?view=azure-devops

Comment: Thank you. That answers it.